# How to connect with Amazon Redshift from Scala

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there any scala driver available to connect with redshift or query with redshift?

Or have any idea that how to fetch the data from redshift using:

```
client = new AmazonRedshiftClient(credentials);
```

I only found the setup of the cluster using `AmazonRedshiftClient` but did not found, How to query of data using `AmazonRedshiftClient`.

Answer (score 0):

To query redshift you can use [Spark-Redshift](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift)